# discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'id' raised an exception: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: json, api, discord, bots

this is the code ` @commands.hybrid_command(
name="id",
description="This command generates fake user data",
)

```
async def id(self, context: Context) -> None:
     async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://api.namefake.com/") as request:
            if request.status == 200:
                fakeid = await request.json(
                    content_type='text/html')  
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="Fake Indentity",
                    description=f"{fakeid['name']['address']}",
                    color=0x9C84EF
                )
            else:`
```

the error is in the tittle. how do make the discord bot display both integer and string

Answer (score 0):

solved description=f"Name:{fakeid['name'],}" Address:{fakeid['address']}, Date of Birth:{fakeid['birth_data']}",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).